# Converting PHP Date to timestamp

Tags: php, date, time, converters

How would I go about changing the following variable into a time stamp?

```
$timenow = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
```

As I am fairly new to PHP please keep as simple answer as possible... thanks in advance!

**Update**

I have the date(); format specified in the database and would like to grab the cell from the database and convert it to time();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two ways which I know.
use this :

```
$timenow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$timestamp = strtotime($timenow);
echo 'time : ' . $timenow . '<br />';
echo 'MY test : ' . $timestamp;
```

My Output executed just now :

```
time : 2013-09-08 15:31:59
MY test : 1378647119
```

OR this:

```
$timestamp = time();
```

Comment: This sounds like it would work but when using it and echoing the first recommendation I get nothing...

Comment: that is because of your time format, if you write time format like example it will work perfect.

Comment: Thanks alot, how do i convert my full `date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')` into the format `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`?

Comment: you don't need to convert, when you call date function it will returns now date, show your date with your format but use example's format for timestamp calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Well that code generates a date based on the current timestamp, so just do this **instead**:

```
$timenow = time();
```

[`time()`](https://www.php.net/time) gives you the current Unix timestamp. Alternatively, you could use [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/strtotime):

```
$timestamp = strtotime($timenow);
```

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear conversion is a MUST, see the update in question